# Href váriavel em NavBar (PHP)

Tags: php

Tenho uma Nav.php e estou dando include em todas as páginas que preciso dela para fazer a navegação do meu sistema, porém estou tendo um problema com os diretórios.

Ex. Se a Nav estiver no dir raiz e eu chamar via href as páginas que estão na raiz Ok, porém se crio uma página em um subdiretorio e dou o include da Nav nesta página a mesma não consegue mais alcançar as páginas do diretório raiz.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão ? Pensei em tentar deixar o href váriavel dependendo do diretório da página.

Abaixo um pedaço da nav:

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" class="dropdown-toggle" 
            data-toggle="dropdown" 
            role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" 
            href="#">
            Tecnologia <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="CatalogoSis.php">Catálogo Sistemas</a></li>
            <li><a href="FerramentasInter.php">Ferramentas Internas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente basta que use o `/`, assim partirá da origem e não do diretório atual.

Isso é, troque isto:

```
<li><a href="CatalogoSis.php">Catálogo Sistemas</a></li>
<li><a href="FerramentasInter.php">Ferramentas Internas</a></li>
```

> Dessa forma acima, se você estiver em `site.com/uma/coisa/index.php`, clicar em "Catálogo Sistemas" levará para `site.com/uma/coisa/CatalogoSis.php`.

Por isto:

```
<li><a href="/CatalogoSis.php">Catálogo Sistemas</a></li>
<li><a href="/FerramentasInter.php">Ferramentas Internas</a></li>
```

> Dessa outra forma, usando o`/`, se você estiver em `site.com/uma/coisa/index.php`, clicar em "Catálogo Sistemas" levará para `site.com/CatalogoSis.php`, ou seja para o arquivo dá raiz.

Comment: Então já havia tentado isso mas não deu certo... por enquanto estou usando o endereço absoluto (http://meusever/dirraiz/subdir/CatalogoSis.php).

Comment: @Leonardo Se as páginas estão na raiz como você especificou na pergunta essa resposta deveria funcionar. Então eu diria que ou você tentou dessa forma mas fez de um jeito diferente que não funcionou ou as páginas não estão de fato na raiz como colocou.

Answer (score -1):

De uma olhada em $_SERVER (https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php)

Acho que $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ou $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] pode te ajudar.